# how to merge array into one

Tags: arrays, arraylist, array-merge, arrayobject

How can I merge the bellow `arrays` in one `array` where the `sectionId` is same ?

```
[

{ segmentStatusId: 1522;  sectionId:1  sequenceNumber: 30;   productSegmentMappingId: 3; customerId: 50; actionTypeId: 10; productId: 20; productOptionId: 0; segmentId: 456; segmentChoiceId: 123; choiceOptionId: 0; isDeleted: fale;},

{ segmentStatusId: 20;  sectionId:1  sequenceNumber: 10;   productSegmentMappingId: 4; customerId: 30; actionTypeId: 10; productId: 20; productOptionId: 0; segmentId: 456; segmentChoiceId: 123; choiceOptionId: 0; isDeleted: fale;},

{ segmentStatusId: 111;  sectionId:4  sequenceNumber: 40;   productSegmentMappingId: 2; customerId: 50; actionTypeId: 10; productId: 20; productOptionId: 0; segmentId: 456; segmentChoiceId: 123; choiceOptionId: 0; isDeleted: fale;},

]
```

Comment: The question you've posted above is wrong. It is an array of objects. I think you are new to stackoverflow. Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before posting any other questions.

Comment: What language are you using?